# One-field interfaces

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, interfaces, swift-language

I have an interface with only one `title` field:

```swift
protocol Artist {
    var title: String { get }
}
```

(A) Should I pass the whole object as I did here:

```swift
class Album {
    func setArtist(_ artist: Artist) {
        /// Handle
    }
}

album.setArtist(artist)
```

(B) Or set that only field:

```swift
class Album {
    func setArtistTitle(_ artistTitle: String) {
        /// Handle
    }
}

album.setArtistTitle(artist.title)
```

What is the recommended way of software design? The (A) solution looks more safer as it is restricted to the type. But the latter (B) is much more flexible. There is no need to create a concrete object, e.g if I want to unit-test my class. The code is less coupled, what we are striving for

EDIT:
All of possible duplicates consider cases with >1 parameters. For me those cases are quite obvious, since multiple parameters form a single type. In my example there is one and only one primitive parameter. The idea of the interface is guarantee existence of `title`, and that's it. The dilemma is where to access the title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's better either pass a class instance to the method or just primitives?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212932/whats-better-either-pass-a-class-instance-to-the-method-or-just-primitives)

Comment: How is B more flexible? Can you give an example operation that can be performed with B, but not with A?

Comment: @DDrmmr Unit test example `album.setArtistTitle("foo"); expect(album.title).equal("foo")`. And similar scenarios where we want to pass a title without creating a concrete object. For example setting a title from an input field. It is still possible to implement with (A) but requires more complicated code and dummy classes like `class ConcreteArtist: Artist { }`. At the same time, we cannot put away the interface, it is needed to make objects compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use A. As you say yourself it is safer and the intention of the code is clearer.

I think you may have a misunderstanding regarding coupling. An Album is *supposed* to be coupled to an Artist. Using a plain string rather than an Artist instance does not reduce this coupling, it just makes the code harder to understand and less safe, since you could by mistake pass something which is not the name of an artist. You can say it is more "flexible" because you can pass arbitrary stuff to `setArtist`, not just `Artists`, but that is not the kind of flexibility you want!

When talk about reducing coupling, we only want to reduce *unnecessary* coupling. like coupling between semantically unrelated objects, or coupling from one object to implementation details of another object rather than just its public interface.

Comment: How should we store the value inside an Album? As `Artist` or `String`? In the first case it seems we could violate the Law of Demeter: `someField.text = album.artist.title`

Comment: @kasyanov-ms: Store it as an Album type for the same reasons.

Comment: The Law of Demeter is really a separate issue, but you should understand the *purpose* of the law. It is not just about counting dots. The text field in your example needs to know the title of the artist of the album in both cases, so replacing the class with a primitive does not change anything conceptually even though it is one dot less.

Comment: Fair point. The last thing I'm confused about is a one-field implementation `class ConcreteArtist: Artist { let title: String }`, which is used when we're forced to pass a String into the method (not a rare scenario). In my view, is a stinkiest code smell

Comment: The [Law of Demeter](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284146/131624) is about not hard coding long dot paths unless you've been promised that they will always work. Cobble long paths together randomly and you turn a flexible code base into an immobile ball of mud.

Comment: @kasyanov-ms: Are you asking if it is always bad design to have a class with just one field?

Comment: @JacquesB In this specific case – a simple adapter for mapping strings. Looks wrong if the method has to always be accompanied with a class